# Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сократить это, чтобы не хардкодить?

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

```
for i, el in enumerate(drivers):
chart = ""
if desc:
    for n, col in enumerate(el):
        if col == '15':
            print(Fore.RED + sep)
        chart += f'| {col:{max_columns[n] + 1}}'
if not desc:
    for n, col in enumerate(el):
        if col == "16":
            print(Fore.RED + sep)
        chart += f'| {col:{max_columns[n] + 1}}'
print(Fore.GREEN + f'{chart}')
```

desc - функция принимает как bool(True|False)

Comment: Желательно выкладывать минимально воспроизводимый код. Хотя я догадываюсь откуда у кода ноги растут :) if (col == '15' and desc) or (col == '16' and not desc):

Comment: @СергейШ да, да это все тот же) и снова спасибо Вам